# Excel macro to compare adjacent cell value and highlight cell with same value in another column

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I have data of questions, choices & answers.

Col-A has questions and choices starting with question 1 and choices A,B,C,D. Similarly I have 500 questions and each has choices.

Col-B has questions & Col-C has correct answers.

I am trying to find the correct answer for each question in Column-B and Column-C, and then highlight the correct answer in Column-A for each question.

Example:
If Question 1 in Col-B has correct answer as B in Col-C, then in Col-A, the question 1 correct choice B must be highlighted in Green color.

Similarly loop for all questions and answers in Col-B & Col-C and highlight all correct choices in Col-A

```
ColA     ColB   ColC  
1        1      B
A        2      A
B        3      A
C
D

2
A
B
C
D

3
A
B
C
D
```

Comment: In a spreadsheet it is much more natural to put the question number,  question, all the answers and the right answer on the same line. Then it becomes a fairly trivial conditional format problem. Your two lists with two different strides makes life more difficult and forces you to use VBA code or fiddly indexing. There would seem to be a missing column in your example containing the actual text of the questions & answers.

Comment: Hi Brown, You are correct. It is Col B which has actual questions and choices. But, I can manage to write VBA code if I get the correct choice highlighted in col-A.

Comment: Do all your questions always have four possible answers, and is your spacing consistent? If so ... I think this is still possible via a conditional formatting formula (though not as trivial as if you can reformat as @MartinBrown suggests).

Comment: Conditional format on $A:$A:
=IF(A1=INDEX(C:C, ROUND(ROW(A1)/6, 0)+1), TRUE, FALSE)

I'll write up a response with screenshots and an explanation.

Comment: Hi Thomas, Yes all questions have 4 choices and one row space between questions. I prefer to have a VBA code.

Comment: If you do want to go the VBA route ... you can use the same formula below to create a VBA solution. Loop through the cells in column A, use their row property to calculate  the row of the corresponding answer in column C. Do your comparison, format the cell, and continue the loop.

Comment: I am not that good at writing VBA code for this kind of complex scenario. Appreciate help to resolve this. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use Dictionary object to track the location (row#) of question index .
- The snippet can handle more choices. (eg. Q2 has 5 choices)

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Dictionary object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Range.End property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.end?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

> [Interior.Color property (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.interior.color?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vbaxl10.chm551073)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue)

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub Demo()
    Dim objDic As Object, rngData As Range
    Dim i As Long, sKey As String, iOffset As Long
    Dim arrData
    Set objDic = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    ' Load data from Col A
    Set rngData = Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(sKey) Then
            objDic(sKey) = i
        End If
    Next i
    ' Clear color formatting on Col A
    Range("A:A").Interior.Color = xlNone
    ' Load data from Col B and C
    Set rngData = Range("B1:C" & Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row)
    arrData = rngData.Value
    ' Loop through data
    For i = LBound(arrData) To UBound(arrData)
        sKey = arrData(i, 1)
        arrData(i, 2) = UCase(arrData(i, 2))
        If objDic.Exists(sKey) Then
            ' The distance between the choice and question index
            iOffset = Asc(arrData(i, 2)) - Asc("A") + 1
            ' Apply color formatting
            With Cells(objDic(sKey) + iOffset, 1)
                If UCase(.Value) = arrData(i, 2) Then _
                    .Interior.Color = vbGreen
            End With
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Taller, Excellent. It works seamlessly. Thanks for your time and support.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your data is formatted as you have described ... you can use a conditional formatting formula. You can use the Column A row number to work out where the answer is in Column C.

The answer for any question x from column A is located at:
INDEX(C:C, ROUND(ROW(Ax)/6, 0)+1)

To test, I've put this formula into column B and fill down:

```
=IF(A1=INDEX(D:D, ROUND(ROW(A1)/6, 0)+1), "yes", "")
```

That puts a 'yes' by the correct answers. For conditional formatting, try this on the range $A:$A (see image):

```
=IF(A1=INDEX(C:C, ROUND(ROW(A1)/6, 0)+1), TRUE, FALSE)
```

[image: data output]

[image: conditional formatting interface]

Comment: Thank Thomas, It works fine on first go, and meets the requirement. But when i tried changing/correcting the answers in column C, it behaves strangely. The cell colors are not applied correctly. Any idea?

Comment: Hmm. Kinda odd - something not re-calculating correctly, then! Try re-opening the conditional formatting manager, re-selecting that particular formatting, and then hit apply. Sorry - without actually seeing your excel file, it's hard to advise further! :( 

Just tried it here - changes to the answers seem to transfer across fine to column A. I'm afraid that's not much help ...

Comment: Ah: if you made changes to C by adding/removing rows ... (not just copying/pasting over the top of the data in column C) then it is possible the conditional formatting assignment (and formula) were auto-changed by Excel. Bit of a pain. Check that the conditional formatting range and formula read as they should. Best to apply the formatting after all the data is stable.

Comment: I did not made any changes to rows or columns. just changed the answers. It is still behaving strangely. some time it is not coloring the correct answers for some question in column A.

Comment: Any chance your data sometimes contains spaces in either column? If so, add a TRIM() (perhaps to both) to clean things up: =IF(TRIM(A1)=TRIM(INDEX(etc etc)))